# Passing value from "select asp-for" to a "textarea" asp.net core razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to know how to pass the value of the asp-for select description to a textarea on the same page after user picks the item.

Cshtml:

```
 <select asp-for="ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.PessoaId" asp-items="Model.ContasReceberVM.PessoaVM.ToSelectListItemNome(Model.ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.PessoaId)" class="form-control"></select>

 <textarea asp-for="ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.Observacao" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Comment: What you mean by "pass" ? You want to update the text area content with the selected option from the SELECT ?

Comment: Also why are you having ` asp-items` for text area ? It does not make any sense!

Comment: @Shyju That's right, why does not it make sense? The asp-items is not part of it, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing code that runs server-side with user interactions that happen client-side. Once the user can do something like select an item from a drop down list, *the server is done*. At that point, all you've got is a DOM created from the HTML that was sent as the server's response. You'd need to use JavaScript to access the select element in the DOM and get its currently selected value. Then, you'd also use JavaScript to select the textarea element from the DOM and alter its content.

Comment: simple example: I have a list of tickets each with a different value, I would like to pass the value of the ticket to the textare or input, according to the selection of the name of the ticket.

So without the javascript there is no way?

Comment: Nope. It's client-side so JS is all you've got.